# nginx to nginx - remote address seems to get lost

Tags: configuration, nginx

I have two nginx instances running on two different machines. `A` acts as proxy for `B` while `B` itself proxies to some nodejs instances.
`B` is compiled with the `ngx_http_realip_module` to fetch the forwarded `X-Real-IP` of `A`. This is the config of `B`:

```
upstream request_proxy{
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

    proxy_pass http://request_proxy;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

All I get in the `request['headers']['x-real-ip']` is `192.168.0.1`, which is the internal IP of `A`.
What am I doing wrong?
Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

I got a same error, seems like we need to save real ip additional like proxy_set_header realip $remote_addr;